# node.js how open/read a XLSX file containing the password

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

I currently use this XLSX tool to open a file but failed.

the XLSX tool:https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

I want to open a file that contains the password, this tool provides a **password variable**, but I can not successfully use, I misunderstood what?

```
var excel = require('xlsx');
filename='./public/test.xlsx';
var workbook = excel.readFile(filename,{password:'123'});
```

server return error 500

Tested have successfully opened file does not contain password.

---

*The tool may not be supported. There are other tools or other methods?

Comment: As per this issue on [Github](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/47) they do not support reading password protected file. There is also a same question on stack overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624684/how-to-read-excel-filepassword-protected-in-nodejs)

Comment: god..,thank. Why provide this password parameters?

Comment: Even I wonder that , you can ask your doubts on the issue page itself , they will answer you better.

Comment: thank!The response rate was not high on that page.

Answer (score 1):

My response is to help answer your question on whether there are other tools or methods to open a password protected xlsx file. I've just been introduced to another node package called xlsx-populate. This package allows you to open an xlsx file that is password protected.

```
XlsxPopulate
.fromFileAsync(__dirname + "/../data/report.xlsx", {password: "password"})
.then(workbook => {
  //do something with the workbook like convert it to csv.
  fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/../data/report.csv", csv, function(err) {
    if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. As discussed here: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/774 this is not an option yet unfortunately and probably will not be implemented in the near future. A workaround for this would be to save file as.. and remove password protection.